# Redis is key to key to value possible

Tags: redis

I think I am trying to design a structure in Redis which is probably wrong.  This is the structure I am trying to store

```
Account number 1
     MAC Address 1 - > {serialized data}
     MAC Address 2 - > {serialized data}
Account number 2
     MAC Address 3 - > {serialized data}
     MAC Address 4 - > {serialized data}
```

I would like to access the data by account number and get the MAC associated with their values.  I would like to also access it by MAC.  From what I am reading this many not be very efficient.

I am thinking I should create 2 sets, one with Account to a list of MACs and another set of MAC to serialized data like below

```
 Account Number 1 - > {Serialized list of MAC addresses} 
 Account Number 2 - > {Serialized list of MAC addresses} 

 MAC Address 1 -> {serialized data}
 MAC Address 2 -> {serialized data}
```

Should I be using Redis for these types of datastores?  Am I on the right trac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [hashes](http://redis.io/commands#hash) to store your data, e.g.:

```
HSET account_1 mac_1 {serialized data}
HSET account_1 mac_2 {serialized data}
HMSET account_2 mac_3 {serialized data} mac_4 {serialized data}
```

It'll cover most of your use cases, allowing you to:

**1.** get serialized data by `account` + `mac` pair

```
HGET account mac
```

**2.** get all `mac` addresses, associated with given `account`

```
HKEYS account
```

**3.** get all data (`mac` addresses and serialized data),  associated with given `account`

```
HGETALL account
```

**4.** get all data without `mac` addresses

```
HVALS account
```

---

The only thing you won't be able to do out of the box is getting serialized data directly by `mac` address without specifying `account`.

So, if you need this information, you'll need to maintain additional dictionary:

```
SET mac_1 account_1
SET mac_2 account_1
SET mac_3 account_2
SET mac_4 account_2
```

Comment: Exactly what I was asking.